# In a sequence of tuples, can I find one given some criteria?

Tags: f#

For example, I'd like to find the tuple that has the minimum date. I tried this

```
let dateRange2 (prices: seq<System.DateTime * float>) =
    let tupleWithMinDate = prices |> Seq.min(fun (date, _) -> date)
    tupleWithMinDate
```

Getting a red squiggly under everything right of the pipeline operator. It says "The type '(seq <System.DateTime * float> -> 'a)' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface"

Not sure if returning a generic type is part of the problem - I assumed Seq.min would know to return the type that the sequence is made of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
let dateRange2 (prices: seq<System.DateTime * float>) = prices |> Seq.minBy fst
```

Comment: There's some discussion of the |> operator on the OCaml mailing list at the moment, as to why we don't use it more

Answer (score 7):

`Seq.min` takes a sequence as its first (and only) argument, not a function.

You want to use `Seq.minBy`.

Comment: In general the `xxxBy` functions take an extra projection that is used for comparison.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx